# truncate inccorrect datetime value 30.05.2012

Tags: mysql, sql

i have problem with my query for date. i have date format for field value 30.05.2012. i want to change this format to 30/05/2012 but my query doesn't work. can i know what wrong with my query?

This is my query:-

```
select DATE_FORMAT(P2, '%d/%m/%Y') from view_parameter a
where a.stateCode = 02 and a.schoolCode='SMSA'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `%` before your d

```
select DATE_FORMAT(P2, '%d/%m/%Y') from view_parameter a where a.stateCode = 02 and a.schoolCode='SMSA'
```

**Edit** :
Oh, that's a string that mysql can't get as a Date : so

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(P2, '%d.%m.%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') ...
```

**Edit 2 :**

or simply (without check for valid dates which is made by STR_TO_DATE)

```
select replace(P2, '.', '/')
```

Comment: thank you very much Raphaël Althaus :). This is the answer select DATE_FORMAT(replace(p2,'.','/'),'%d/%m/%Y') from view_parameter a
where a.stateCode = 02 and a.schoolCode='SMSA' :)